# How to view Journal data of a Table Green screen DB2

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

How do you view journal data from a specified table? I want to see what happended to a table in a specified time frame.

I got info on the table by using the following command:
DSPFD FILE(P6PRDBDB00/P6OIDPF)

[image]

[image]

Got the journaled  name and library but I dont know how to view it for the object P6OIDPF?

I did go to library #MXJRN and whent to P6 and got the following :
[image]

How can I view the object P6OIDPF data? Or a command to view it?
Theres a lot of objects in P6.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command to use is `DSPJRN JRN(#MXJRN/P6) FILE((P6PRDBDB00/P6OIDPF))`

You can Filter on start and end date time.

Comment: FWiW: The `Journaled Physical File (FILE) - Help` of the Display Journal (DSPJRN) command [and\or command and usage documentation] could be useful to help the OP to understand the results for a [non]existing member or file, and how the use of the Journal Identifier(s) (JID) can impact that request, for which journal entries will be selected\extracted and thus converted for output.  As well, a review of the `Element 2: Member' help text may be worthwhile; the example shown here, defaults to determine which JID, from only the first (*FIRST) member. Ignoring these nuances can be problematic.

Answer (score 4):

The EXPJRNE utility from [Tools/400](http://www.tools400.de/English/Freeware/Utilities/utilities.html) provides a higher level interface to the [DSPJRN](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/cl/dspjrn.htm?lang=en) command.

Answer (score 3):

Follow the next sequence:

Get the data file length and use it in the next command

```
DSPJRN JRN(JRNLIB/JRN)            
   FILE((FILELIB/DATAFILE *FIRST))
   OUTPUT(*OUTFILE)           
   OUTFILFMT(*TYPE2)          
   OUTFILE(OUTFILELIB/OUTFILE)
   ENTDTALEN(datafilelength)
```

Once you get the data with wrkqry create a joined table where you get all the outfile fields except the last one JOESD. Instead of JOESD, you get all the data fields.

```
                        Specify File Selections                  

Type choices, press Enter.  Press F9 to specify an additional       
 file selection.                                                   

File . . . . . . . . .   OUTFILE        Name, F4 for list         
 Library  . . . . . .     *LIBL        Name, *LIBL, F4 for list  
Member . . . . . . . .   *FIRST         Name, *FIRST, F4 for list 
Format . . . . . . . .   *FIRST         Name, *FIRST, F4 for list 
File ID  . . . . . . .   A              A-Z99, *ID                

File . . . . . . . . .   datafile       Name, F4 for list         
 Library  . . . . . .     *LIBL        Name, *LIBL, F4 for list  
Member . . . . . . . .   *FIRST         Name, *FIRST, F4 for list 
Format . . . . . . . .   *FIRST         Name, *FIRST, F4 for list 
File ID  . . . . . . .   B              A-Z99, *ID
```

the join is not important

```
                       Specify How to Join Files                            

Type comparisons to show how file selections are related, press Enter.         
Tests:  EQ, NE, LE, GE, LT, GT                                               

Field             Test     Field                                               
A.JOENTL          EQ       ANYFIELD
```

Select all the fields but JOESD.

```
                      Select and Sequence Fields                           

Type sequence number (0-9999) for the names of up to 500 fields to            
appear in the report, press Enter.                                          

Seq   Field             Text                                          Len  Dec
1     A.JOMBR           Name of Member                                 10     
1     A.JOCTRR          Count or relative record number changed        10    0
1     A.JOFLAG          Flag: 1 or 0                                    1     
1     A.JOCCID          Commit cycle identifier                       10    0
1     A.JOUSPF          User Profile                                   10     
1     A.JOSYNM          System Name                                     8     
1     A.JOINCDAT        Incomplete Data: 1 or 0                         1     
1     A.JOMINESD        Minimized ESD: 0, 1, or 2                       1     
1     A.JORES           Not used                                       18     
      A.JOESD           Entry Specific Data - Variable contents       808     
1     B.FIELD1          FIELD1                                          2     
1     B.FIELD2          FIELD2                                          3    0
```

Then just copy from the outfile to the jrn file with replace and *nochk

```
CPYF FROMFILE(QTEMP/OUTFILE)  
   TOFILE(QTEMP/JRN)        
   MBROPT(*REPLACE)         
   FMTOPT(*NOCHK)
```

And that's it! In JRN you have all the journal data and the data file data formatted as in the original file.

Comment: An important element is that when creating the JOIN file description, you usually do not want to populate the resulting file. If you populate it at creation time, try to select only a few records. You only want to create the FD for later use in the CPYF command. Create the JOIN FD once, and save it for future use.

Comment: WRKQRY from the 80's? I do much the same thing with SQL.  A far more powerful and flexible tool.

Comment: Man, you still use pants, right? Those have 4 centuries or more. Simply there are things that are just right for the job. I dare you to do the same thing with SQL. Let me know if you can do it and I will bow unto you.

Answer (score 0):

You have system procedure DISPLAY_JOURNAL and DISPLAY_JOURNAL_ENTRY_INFO  in last versions of DB2

[DISPLAY_JOURNAL doc](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/IBM%20i%20Technology%20Updates/page/DISPLAY_JOURNAL%20(easier%20searches%20of%20Audit%20Journal))