# How to view a Deleted records data using journal data

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I have a table that has journal data.

I ran the following command to output the journal data to a table(`P6TMPLIB1`) for me to query.

```
DSPJRN JRN(#MXJRN/P6) FILE((P6PRDBDB00/P6prodPF)) ENTTYP(*RCD) OUTPUT(*OUTFILE) OUTFILFMT(*TYPE3) OUTFILE(p6prdbdb00/P6TMPLIB1)
```

When I do a select from `P6TMPLIB1` I get the following.

[image]

With this data I can see that there was a Delete but in the `JOESD` field there is no data.

If theres an update to the table I can see the data in the field `JOESD`

What I want to see is what data was deleted or the key of the record that was deleted.

Is this posible? And how do I view the DL record?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to see the deleted record data, your file has to be set to journal before and after records. `STRJRNPF  IMAGES(*BOTH)`

At this point, there's not much you can do.

However, what you could do is sort the journal output by RRN and SEQ#.  Hopefully you'll be able to see the last write.  Thus you'll know what was there when it was deleted.

Unfortunately, that technique becomes much more difficult if you're re-using deleted records or doing RGZPFM.

Answer (score 1):

Use this technique [How-to-view-journal-data-of-a-table-green-screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30433651/how-to-view-journal-data-of-a-table-green-screen-db2/30452797#30452797). 15 years and I haven't found a better way to analize journals.