# IBM iSeries : fulls details of journal entries (type R)

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, analysis, audit, journal

I need to analyze the journal entries of type R for DB2 on iSeries in order to be able to audit all sql requests (Insert, Update,Delete) generating changes on data : in fact, i would like to analyze the ENTRY_DATA field as returned by QSYS2.Display_Journal in order to dissect image-before / image after of changed lines.

I can't find the appropriate IBM doc / web url providing all details on those entries. Can somebody point me to such details ?

Comment: Check this entry... [Display Journal Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30433651/how-to-view-journal-data-of-a-table-green-screen-db2/30452797#30452797) 15 years and I still use it...

Comment: It's not clear what you're looking for. IBM can't document type R ENTRY_DATA because you define it. It's essentially nothing more than the record formats of your files, not IBM formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract before/after image from journal.

Simply copy the joesd to a flat file.  Then copy flat file to database *NOCHK

This code gets the after image.

```
? DSPJRN ?*JRN(mylib/myJRN)
           OUTPUT(*OUTFILE) 
           OUTFILFMT(*TYPE3)
           OUTFILE(QTEMP/Z1)
           ENTDTALEN(*CALC)

insert into myflatfil
SELECT joesd FROM qtemp/z1 WHERE JOENTT = 'UP'

cpyf myflatfil mydatabase *nochk
```

Comment: Hi Danny, exactly what I was looking for. Problem solved. Thanks !

Comment: Hi Danny, just to confirm : we just coded the analysis of ENTRY_DATA field and it works as expected -> we can recover all columns of our tables with their proper value before and after update. Thanks again

Comment: Tip If you make your flat file with one big field named joesd you can cpyf *map *drop.  Instead of using the SQL.

Comment: Hi danny117, thanks for the tip but using sql is fine for us.

Answer (score 2):

Starting point for journal info is here: [Journal entry information](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzaki/rzakijrnentry.htm?lang=en)

Note that while Display_Journal() is nice, it may not be all that useful for your purposes as it returns the before and after image of the record as a BLOB.    Each ENTRY_DATA format would be unique to the file being journaled. Plus, there isn't for instance a built in way to convert a substring of the blob back into a readable packed decimal value.

The Journal APIs would probably be a better choice.

But a generic audit tool that uses the journals is a non-trivial task.

Best choice would be to simply buy a third party tool designed to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi Charles, thanks a lot for your infos ! Can you point me to such a tool that you mention ?

Comment: Here's a couple, http://www.kisco.com/ifa/summary.htm  and http://townsendsecurity.com/products/file-integrity-monitoring-advanced-tools

Comment: Hi Charles,I'll study them and see if they match our need. I will also try what Danny proposes herebelow.

Answer (score 0):

> Export Journal Entries V4.9
>
> The EXPJRNE command exports journal entries of fiels, data areas and
>   data queues to an output file. The output file has the same layout as
>   the journalized file plus the journaling information. EXPJRNE makes it
>   really easy to analyze journal entries by SQL.

[EXPJRNE](http://www.tools400.de/English/Freeware/Utilities/utilities.html)